# Query to Select Only One row for one date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need a help to select only last one updated row for the punch in/out for one day.

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT     
    convert(nvarchar(20), EmpID) as EmpID, ID, 
    DATENAME(dw, date1) AS day, date1 AS date, 
    PunchDateTime AS timein,  
    COALESCE((SELECT MAX(PunchDateTime) AS Expr1
              FROM PunchData AS b 
              WHERE empid = '61039' 
                AND (EmpID = a.EmpID)  
                AND (PunchType = 4) 
                AND PunchDateTime between a.PunchDateTime and dateadd(hour, 17, a.PunchDateTime)), 
             (SELECT MIN(PunchDateTime) AS Expr1
              FROM PunchData AS b
              WHERE empid = '61039'
                AND (EmpID = a.EmpID) 
                AND (ID >= a.ID) 
                AND (PunchType = 1) 
                AND date1 = a.date1), 0)  AS timeout
FROM         
    dbo.PunchData AS a
WHERE    
    empid = '61039'
    AND (PunchType = 1)
GROUP BY 
    EmpID, ID, DATENAME(dw, date1), date1, PunchDateTime

UNION ALL

SELECT     
    convert(nvarchar(20), EmpID) as EmpID, ID, 
    DATENAME(dw, dateadd(hour, -12, PunchDateTime)) AS day,
    convert(date, COALESCE((SELECT Min(PunchDateTime) AS Expr1
                            FROM PunchData AS b 
                            WHERE EmpID = '61039'
                              AND (EmpID = a.EmpID)  
                              AND (PunchType = 1) 
                              AND PunchDateTime between dateadd(hour, -17,  a.PunchDateTime)  
                                                    and a.PunchDateTime),
                           dateadd(hour, -12, PunchDateTime))) AS date,  
    COALESCE((SELECT Min(PunchDateTime) AS Expr1
              FROM PunchData AS b 
              WHERE EmpID = '61039' 
                AND (EmpID = a.EmpID)  
                AND (PunchType = 1) 
                AND PunchDateTime between dateadd(hour, -17, a.PunchDateTime)  
                                      and a.PunchDateTime), 
             (SELECT Max(PunchDateTime) AS Expr1
              FROM PunchData AS b
              WHERE EmpID = '61039'
                AND (EmpID = a.EmpID) 
                AND (ID = a.ID) 
                AND (PunchType = 4) 
                AND date1 = a.date1), 0)  AS timein,
    PunchDateTime as timeout  
FROM         
    dbo.PunchData AS a
WHERE     
    (PunchType = 4) 
    AND empid = '61039'
GROUP BY 
    EmpID, ID, DATENAME(dw, date1), date1, PunchDateTime
```

[SQL output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QSp6.png)

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (`SELECT`, `FROM`, `CONVERT`), or write them in all lowercase (select, from, convert), or in mixed case (Select, From, Convert) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the whole query in a CTE and then do a subsequent select from the CTE perhaps?

something like this perhaps :

```
;with mycte as (
select 1 as ID , '2017-08-01' as date1 
union all 
select 1 as ID , '2017-08-02' as date1 
)

Select distinct mycte.*
 from mycte
 inner join mycte mycte2
    on mycte.ID = mycte2.ID
        and mycte.date1 = (select max(mycte3.date1) from mycte mycte3 where mycte3.id = mycte.ID)
```

Comment: i did it but after that how i can only select the last updated row